# Is there away to change the colors of context menu on cefsharp Icontextmenu?

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

Can we change the backcolor, forecolor, and mousehover on Icontextmenu on cefsharp (Chromium).

Comment: Not directly, you can implement your own custom context menu.